How do I just this conjecture?
I have 6 equations:

$X_1=As+B_1t_1+B_2t_2$
$X_2=As+B_1t_2+B_2t_1$
$X_3=A_3s+B_3t_3$
$Y_1=C(X_1+t_1)$
$Y_2=C(X_2+t_2)$
$Y_3=D(X_3+t_3)$

where $X_1,X_2,X_3,Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,s,t_1,t_2,t_3$ are variables and $A,B_1,B_2,A_3,B_3,C,D$ are coefficients.
How can I adjust/rewrite the 6 equations such that $Y_1+Y_2=Y_3$ always holds? Specifically, can I rewrite the last three equations as

$Y_1=C(X_1+t_1-k)$
$Y_2=C(X_2+t_2-k)$
$Y_3=D(X_3+t_3+k)$

where $k$ is some combination of the other variables and/or coefficients such that $Y_1+Y_2=Y_3$ holds regardless of the taken values?

It's a bit unclear what you are allowed to change and what you aren't allowed to change. Let's assume that we have some expression for $k \neq 0$. How would you be able to rewrite
$$Y_1 = C(X_1 + t_1)$$
as
$$ Y_1 = C(X_1 + t_1 - k) $$ ? Isn't that a contradiction?

Sorry for the confusion. The three $Y$ equations without $k$ are wrong, so I know they should include the $k$. I just want to find the $k$ (as a combination of the other variables and/or coefficients) such that the constraint $Y_1+Y_2=Y_3$ always holds. I cannot have any restriction on $D$ and $C$.

Well, if you just do the algebra:
$$
Y_1 + Y_2 = Y_3
$$
$$C(X_1 + X_2+t_1 + t_2) - 2Ck = D(X_3 + t_3) + Dk $$
$$C(X_1 + X_2 + t_1 + t_2) - D(X_3 + t_3) = Dk - 2Ck = (D-2C)k$$
$$
k = \frac{
C(X_1 + X_2 + t_1 + t_2) - D(X_3 + t_3)
}{
D-2C
}
$$

When you typed just in the title, did you mean adjust?

Did you make any progress in this?

@MattiP, please post it as an answer.

Simply applying algebra, we get
$$
Y_1 + Y_2 = Y_3
$$
$$
C(X_1 + X_2 + t_1 + t_2) - 2Ck = D(X_3 + t_3) + Dk
$$
$$
C(X_1 + X_2 + t_2 + t_2) - D(X_3+t_3) = Dk - 2Ck = (D-2C)k
$$
And we get $k$:
$$
k = \frac{C}{D-2C}\left(X_1 + t_1 \right) +\frac{C}{D-2C}\left(X_2 + t_2 \right) - \frac{D}{D-2C} \left(X_3 + t_3 \right)
$$
